# How to install netbeans on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

I have just installed Ubuntu for the first time - in a virtual machine.  (I don't have much linux experience).

Now I'm trying to install netbeans.  I have downloaded netbeans, which seems to be a .sh file of 43 Mb, but I'm not sure how to execute it...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two way to do it. You can use the downloaded file for install it.

```
cd /path/where/the/file/is
sh ./netbeansblablabla.sh
```

But you can install it with the synaptic packet manager (netbeans, like other soft installed by this way will be updated automatically with other system updates). For this way, use apt-get install:

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Or search it in software manager of ubuntu.

;)